# Fold/wrap long lines in w3m

Tags: w3m

I'm looking for an option to wrap lines of rendered HTML in w3m when they reach a certain length, say 72 characters. By default the text spans the entire width of the window and reading becomes difficult. Here's a screenshot of how an article looks by default in fullscreen w3m:

[image: w3m crappy long lines]

In newsbeuter I was able to get the behavior I wanted easily with `text-width 72`. The same article with text nicely wrapped in newsbeuter:

[image: newsbeuter nicely wrapped text]

**Is there a way to achieve this kind of line-wrapping at 72 characters in w3m?**

The data for the views above is available at this url:

https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2017/05/why_the_politic.html

Comment: Have you tried anything or has your research pointed you in any specific or particular direction for any potential solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Run `w3m` with relevant options to dump formatted page to standard output, then pipe the standard output to `less` command. However, no such options in w3m configuration file.

Manual page w3m(1) has mentioned the following options.

```
   -dump  dump formatted page into stdout

   -cols width
          specify column width (used with -dump)
```

To set column width at 72, use those options like this:

```
w3m -dump -cols 72 [URL or filename]
```

Since `-dump` option produce standard output, you can't really do normal browsing (w3m will dump formatted page and exit). Pipe to `less` to browse the formatted page.

```
w3m -dump -cols 72 [URL or filename] | less
```

The last one-line command is all you need.

### Normal browsing by w3m

[image: Browse w3m article on Wikipedia using w3m]

### Formatted page browsing by w3m and less

[image: Browse w3m article on Wikipedia using w3m with dump option and pipe to less]

Notice that first-half of the page is wrapped nicely within the column width specified. The screenshots above are browsing this article: [w3m on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3m).

**Remarks**: The `-dump` option will remove the hyperlinks all together when producing the formatted page. If column width is the only criteria that you need, this option will suffice. Besides this, I am not aware of other ways to also preserve the hyperlinks.

Comment: Would it be possible to get the wrapping right by feeding the html through Newsbeuter to w3m?

Comment: @dionys I don't think so. Newsbeuter is an RSS/Atom reader, which display the contents from feed and *not* from HTML page itself. Like [this RSS 2.0 feed of source](https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/index.xml) include 'clean' content of articles, but not shown in RSS 1.0 nor Atom (also depends on blog setup).

Comment: Is it possible to set this every time you open w3m as a new standard width?

Answer (score 4):

You could simply change the terminal's number of columns through `stty`, e.g., `stty cols 72` and then run `w3m <url>`. That's what I do sometimes.

There are two problems with this, however:

1. Even if you aliased `w3m` to `stty cols 72 && w3m`, you'd still have to reset the line width after your browsing session if you don't want it to stay at 72 columns. This could be automated through a little wrapper script, though.
2. When you're in an X terminal, the `stty` setting will be void as soon as you resize the window. (I've tested this in xterm and urxvt.)

Comment: Howto reset `stty` when you quit w3m? Can we remap q in w3m?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 'read shell' command (default @ key) to set the width with the `stty colls number` command on the fly. It will open a new buffer but you can go back and the page will be render with the new width.